# Which resource is used by Cloud Monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm trying to automatize the creation of a Monitoring Dashboard with Terraform and IaC.

I've seen [this](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/monitoring_dashboard), and I understand that I can add the JSON code of the dashboard as it follows in the documentation.

My question is: where will I find the dashboard inside GCP?

Thanks :)

```
resource "google_monitoring_dashboard" "dashboard" {
  dashboard_json = <<EOF
{
  "displayName": "Grid Layout Example",
  "gridLayout": {
    "columns": "2",
    "widgets": [
      {
        "title": "Widget 1",
        "xyChart": {
          "dataSets": [{
            "timeSeriesQuery": {
              "timeSeriesFilter": {
                "filter": "metric.type=\"agent.googleapis.com/nginx/connections/accepted_count\"",
                "aggregation": {
                  "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_RATE"
                }
              },
              "unitOverride": "1"
            },
            "plotType": "LINE"
          }],
          "timeshiftDuration": "0s",
          "yAxis": {
            "label": "y1Axis",
            "scale": "LINEAR"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "text": {
          "content": "Widget 2",
          "format": "MARKDOWN"
        }
      },
      {
        "title": "Widget 3",
        "xyChart": {
          "dataSets": [{
            "timeSeriesQuery": {
              "timeSeriesFilter": {
                "filter": "metric.type=\"agent.googleapis.com/nginx/connections/accepted_count\"",
                "aggregation": {
                  "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_RATE"
                }
              },
              "unitOverride": "1"
            },
            "plotType": "STACKED_BAR"
          }],
          "timeshiftDuration": "0s",
          "yAxis": {
            "label": "y1Axis",
            "scale": "LINEAR"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

EOF
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dashboard is in the GCP console under `Monitoring->Dashboards` menu, in the `Opertions` sub-group.
You can also find it in this link below, just replace the "YOUR-PROJECT-ID-HERE" with your GCP project ID.
https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/dashboards?project=YOUR-PROJECT-ID-HERE

If the terraform code you posted is created successfully, it will show up with a dashboard named `Grid Layout Example`, with in the GCP project defined for your terraform code.

Google documentation for reference - https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/predefined-dashboards

Comment: Another question: do I need to import specific module to call this function?
Such as: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/cloud-operations/google/0.2.3

Comment: You don't have to. All you need is the google provider bock - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference